# How to fix these errors in Redux-React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have errors: 
[image]
Redux I just started studying, please help correct my code that my Redux application finally started working as it works on pure React.
All project Here I will write only a few major project filesHere I will write only a few major project files
Here I will write only a few major project files
Here I will write only a few major project files

Here I will write only a few major project files

App.js(components):

```
export function searchFilter (search, data) {                                               
  return data.filter(n => n.term.toLowerCase().includes(search));
}

export const days = ["23-08-2019", "24-08-2019", "25-08-2019"];        

class Root extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onFetchData(this.props.day);
  }

  render() {
   const { search, shift, data, filteredData, onFilter, onSetSearch, onFetchData } = this.props;

   return (
      <div>
        <TableSearch value={search}
          onChange={(e) => onSetSearch(e.target.value)} 
          onSearch={() => onFilter()} />

        {days && days.map((day, i) => (
          <button key={day} 
            onClick={() => onFetchData(day)}
            className={i === day ? "active" : ""}>{day}</button>
        ))}
        <br />
        {data && Object.keys(data).map(n => (
          <button data-shift={n}
            onClick={(e) => onFilter({ shift: e.target.dataset.shift })}
            className={n === shift ? "active" : ""}>{n} shift</button>
        ))}

        {data && <TableData data={filteredData} /> }

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export const ConnectedRoot = connect(             
  (state) => state,
  (dispatch) => ({
    onFilter: (args) => dispatch({ type: 'RUN_FILTER', ...args }),
    onSetSearch: (search) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_SEARCH', search }),
    onFetchData: (day) => dispatch(fetchData(day))
  })
)(Root);
```

reducer:

```
 import { searchFilter } from '../components/app';
 export function reducer (state = {}, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
      case 'SET_SHIFT':
         return Object.assign({}, state, {
            shift: action.shift
         });
      case 'SET_SEARCH':
         return Object.assign({}, state, {
            search: action.search.toLowerCase()
         });
      case 'RUN_FILTER':
         return Object.assign({}, state, {
            shift: action.shift || state.shift,
            search: action.search || state.search,
            filteredData: searchFilter(state.search, state.data[state.shift])
         });
      case 'LOAD_DATA_START':
         return Object.assign({}, state, {
            day: action.day
         });
      case 'LOAD_DATA_END':
         return Object.assign({}, state, {
            data: action.data,
            shift: Object.keys(action.data)[0],
            filteredData: searchFilter(state.search, state.data[state.shift])
         });
      default:
         return state;
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to give data property an initial value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you're not getting anything back from the API (`404`). See the image below.

[image]

This is because your `${day}` value when the component loads is `undefined`. So your full request URL is `https://api.iev.aero/api/flights/undefined` which is returning nothing.

Now you're dispatching `LOAD_DATA_START` so when you get to your reducer and hit the `case "LOAD_DATA_START` line, `action.day` is still `undefined`. So for `action.data` you're getting an empty array. This brings us to `LOAD_DATA_END` where you set the state value for `shift` equal to `Object.keys(action.data)[0]`. Since `action.data` is an empty, `Object.keys(action.data)[0]` is `undefined` and you're app can't filter with `undefined`. You need have a default value for `this.state.day` and use that on your initial fetch.

**UPDATE 1**

You need to pass a default value in the initial fetch. Try something like this in your `componentDidMount`:

```
const days = ["23-08-2019", "24-08-2019", "25-08-2019"];

class Root extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.onFetchData(days[this.props.propReducer.day]);
    }
    ...
 }
```

There's no need to export the `days` array just declare it as a variable above of the component.

**UPDATE 2**

I've updated the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-4mt27). A few things were changed here.

First, your redux actions were being stored in `this.props`, but your redux state was being stored in `this.props.propReducer`, so in the render I changed the variables so they pointed to the correct location.

Next, you were dispatching `SET_SHIFT` immediately after `LOAD_DATA_END` and passing `data` as the payload. This was setting `state.shift` as the data returned from the initial fetch. So when you tried to filter data by `state.shift` any other time aside from when you first made the fetch in `componentDidMount` you were trying to separate the `action.data` at the key of the entire previously fetched data. I removed this and set it as a separate action entirely.

Now, in order to properly filter your data, I passed both the retrieved data **and** the passed day in `fetchData` as two values in the payload for `LOAD_DATA_END` See below.

```
 dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_END", payload: { data, day } });
```

And finally, in you reducer under the case for `"LOAD_DATA_END"`, I wrote the below.

```
 var newData = action.payload.data[state.shift].filter(x => {
    return (
      x.actual &&
      x.actual.includes(
        action.payload.day
          .split("-")
          .reverse()
          .join("-")
      )
    );
  });
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    data: action.payload.data,
    shift: Object.keys(action.payload.data)[0],
    filteredData: searchFilter(state.search, newData)
  });
```

What happens here is first you separate the `action.payload.data` by the key of `state.shift`, which returns one array, either the arrivals or departures. Then I filter this array based on what flights have an `actual` (which I assumed was the actual date and time of arrival/departure) that includes the passed day. I have to reverse the date though because in `actual` the times looked like `2019-08-24T00:27:49Z` whereas the day looked like `24-08-2019`. This is also why I used `includes` and not `===` because `actual` contains more information than just the date, it also contains the time. Now your data has been properly filtered and can be passed to the final filtration, `searchFilter` which I will leave up to you to determine how best to filter based on user input (either by time, flight number, terminal, etc).

If you check the codepen, you should now be able to filter by the shift and the day.

Comment: I just tried your code sandbox and it works. You just needed to pass a default value for `${day}` on your initial fetch and now it works.

Comment: Ah I see. I've edited my answer. You need to do `this.props.propsReducer...` instead of `this.props...` and then you can just declare `days` as a variable above your `App` component.

Comment: i did as you said unfortunately nothing has changed. New sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-t1r2k

Comment: I'm actually still working on it now there's more wrong with it than I thought

Comment: ok, thank you very much! you're probably my last hope that this app will ever work, I'll wait

Comment: I've updated the answer and linked to a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-4mt27) that should work now.

Comment: thank you very much!) you are a wonderful person! I wish you success in everything!) you do not imagine how happy I am) Сan I ask another question? Why when i press button ```arrival shift``` and then I press button ```departure shift ``` the data in the city field disappear. Try pressing these two buttons one by one and you will see a problem(try again several times). Maybe tell me how to solve it?

Comment: No problem and thanks for the well wishes! I checked it out and it's because arrivals have `airportFromID.city_en` whereas departures have `airportToID.city_en`. Previously `TableData` was only rendering `airportToID.city_en` and since arrivals don't have that as a property it would render nothing. I've updated the code sandbox.

Comment: now when I press button arrival shift or departure shift,all disappear, and symply white page in sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-4mt27

Comment: [I fixed it](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-t78mi). Check it now. In `RUN_FILTER` the filtering wasn't being done and `newData` was undefined. You should really inspect the console more. `TableData` couldn't `map undefined`, meaning the `filteredData` prop being passed was not being properly set in state after you applied the shift filter.